# Using Aforge.Net library in .Net CF application?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, mobile

Can a desktop .net library [Aforge.net] be used in a .Net CF 3.5 application? I agree that the CF is a subset and all... that certain functions etc will not work... but the error i am getting is baffling...

```
AForge.Imaging.Filters.ResizeBilinear resizeBilinear = new ResizeBilinear(240, 320);
Bitmap new1 = resizeBilinear.Apply(new System.Drawing.Bitmap(10,10));
```

The Apply() expects a System.Drawing.Bitmap object, which is exactly what i am passing... But for some reason the app will not build. The error i get is as follows:

```
The type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

The best overloaded method match for 'AForge.Imaging.Filters.FilterAnyToAnyNew.Apply(System.Drawing.Bitmap)' has some invalid arguments
```

Is there something i am missing out on? I obviously have referenced the System.Drawing dll and have used it in my code. The Aforge.Net namespace doesnot redefine the Bitmap or something like that...

I am unable to understand why its not able to recognize that the passed object is indeed a Bitmap object...

please help...

Comment: found a msdn forum post with the exact same problem...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/3363fa03-d5bb-43f1-bd49-d193d4c94951/

seems you just cannot use a desktop library in .net cf ap...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use a desktop assembly under the CF at all.  You can go the other way - full desktop assemblies can consume CF assemblies, but there's no way to get a CF app to use a desktop assembly without recompiling it.

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds, you need to have ver 2.0 of the CF or recompile AForge for CF on 3.5.